# How to use spark in python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

First of all I`m talking about Apache spark.
And I know that I can submit my python application in this way.

```
bin/spark-submit myApp.py
```

The problem is that this is a shell command line. But what I want is using python to call this. I want use python to call the computation process and get the result.
I know that I can do it in this way

```
import os
os.system("bin/spark-submit myApp.py")
```

But I think this is not a good way. Is there other way I can do this?

Regards
Mingwei

Comment: Is it for developpement? If it is, have a look at the IPython notebook http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I will check the ipython notebook. But I do not understand what you mean. What I want is to get the spark computation result in my python code. Not from a shell output. So I can use those result in some other purpose like returning them as REST api result..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `spark-submit`. If you look at [`SparkSubmit.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.5.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala) you can see it does quite a lot of things. You could probably read that code and set things up yourself the way you want, but that setup may not work with the next version of Spark. `spark-submit` is the only method guaranteed to work across versions.

This should not be very limiting generally. You can have long-running Spark applications. The application I'm working on is a web server that also runs Spark jobs, and it's started with `spark-submit` as well.

Comment: There are some pros and cons to this. The long-running application will use up cluster resources (memory of the executors) even when it is idle. On the other hand it will be able to re-use results from previous runs, e.g. shuffle outputs and cached RDDs.

Answer (score -1):

go to spark directions.
and write this code

```
./bin/pyspark
```

And after you will se like this.

```
NFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/10/15 11:51:43 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:34663 with 265.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 34663)
15/10/15 11:51:43 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.2.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015 17:58:13)
SparkContext available as sc.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But I do not understand your mean. Are you saying I can replace the interpreter in my python script from #!/usr/bin/python to #!/.../bin/pyspark  ?